# How to start arbitrarily many identical containers with docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose

I am testing a typical load-balancing setting with *docker.* For this I need to start a container running a *load balancer* acting as a proxy to access an arbitrarily large pool of *workers* running in their containers.

How can I build my *docker-compose* file or command line, to be able to specify how many containers running a *worker* I want to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose scale` is the command you're looking for.